# Is this query really unsafe?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb

The following query is executing as desired however when i execute via my remote admin tool (heidisql) I am receiving a message that states:

> Note: Unsafe statement written to the binary log using statement format since BINLOG_FORMAT = STATEMENT. Statements writing to a table with an auto-increment column after selecting from another table are unsafe because the order in which rows are retrieved determines what (if any) rows will be written. This order cannot be predicted and may differ on master and the slave.

The query is as follows:

```
UPDATE t016sliderimages AS t016

JOIN t004images AS t004
ON t004.ImageID = t016.ImageID

JOIN t034imagealbums AS t034
ON t004.ImageAlbumID = t034.ImageAlbumID


SET t016.SliderNumber = t016.SliderNumber - 1

WHERE t034.ItemID = 32
AND t016.SliderNumber > 4
```

Could this be a false positive or is there something wrong with this query even though it appears to be doing what is desired?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a table with key values 1, 2, 3 for example, and you wanted the values to start at zero, you could say `set key = key - 1` and, for most DBMSs, that would be good enough. However, in this regard, MySQL is not like most DBMSs. Suppose it tried to update the row with ID=3 first. Subtract one and the new ID would be 2. But there is already a row with ID=2 in the table. Bad mojo.

So, and again this applies only to MySQL (that I know), you have to explicitly specify an `order by` so that such collisions cannot happen. In this case, you must force it to start at the lowest values and work up.

```
    SET t016.SliderNumber = t016.SliderNumber - 1
WHERE   t034.ItemID = 32
    AND t016.SliderNumber > 4
ORDER BY t016.SliderNumber ASC;
```

However, you are starting at values larger than 4. So if the first value above that is 5, then you have to make sure there is no value = 4. KnoWhaddaMean?

**Update:** I found a [reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) for this behavior. Look for the paragraph that starts "If an UPDATE statement includes an ORDER BY clause..."